# Azure Flexible Postgres: `permission denied for table pg_authid` diring `pg_dumpall -r`

Tags: postgresql, azure

I have an Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server.

I'm trying to upgrade using the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/how-to-upgrade-using-dump-and-restore#upgrade-your-databases-using-offline-migration-methods).

The first step is to dump the roles

```
pg_dumpall -r --host=mySourceServer --port=5432 --username=myUser --database=mySourceDB > roles.sql
```

This fails with

```
pg_dumpall: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for table pg_authid
pg_dumpall: error: query was: SELECT oid, rolname, rolsuper, rolinherit, rolcreaterole, rolcreatedb, rolcanlogin, rolconnlimit, rolpassword, rolvaliduntil, rolreplication, rolbypassrls, pg_catalog.shobj_description(oid, 'pg_authid') as rolcomment, rolname = current_user AS is_current_user FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname !~ '^pg_' ORDER BY 2
```

I'm running it under an admin username.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dump all the roles with passwords from the source **Single Server** only.  It is **not** possible to do the same from the Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server. It is provided in the same [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/how-to-upgrade-using-dump-and-restore#migrate-the-roles).

> To dump all the roles names, **without passwords** from the source **Flexible Server**:

```
pg_dumpall -r  --no-role-passwords  --host=mySourceServer --port=5432  --username=myUser --database=mySourceDB > roles.sql
```

[image]

Comment: yep, it's now provided in the same doc (probably after I contacted MS support, but it could also be just a coincidence). It wasn't at the time of writing a question